# NStableview sort with selectedRow still be the first focus

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I implemented a delegate method tableView:didClickTableColumn:
and inside this method I made an ascending or descending sort per click volume, but here is the thing, after I click, the sort can be finished, but focus got wrong. It selects all the rows, I want to select the same row index item before sorting.

Comment: Is the column selected or all columns?

Comment: @Willeke I have found the reason, the default behaviour maybe select all rows in column, but if you implement a delegate method called shouldSelectColumn, return NO, you can stop it

Comment: You can switch of Column Selection or `allowsColumnSelection`. Why do you override `didClickTableColumn` instead of using the built-in sorting mechanism?